# I need to be able to match a date and store number to an array that has the store numbers, a date range and return the PO Number on that line

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is a sample of the data:

```
Start Date  End Date  Store #   PO #
11/21/2015  11/27/2015  6684    6454751918
11/21/2015  11/27/2015  4835    7154792466
11/21/2015  11/27/2015  6601    8054772062
11/21/2015  11/27/2015  6682    8404731939
11/21/2015  11/27/2015  6687    8454732305
11/21/2015  11/27/2015  6685    9004781937
11/18/2015  11/24/2015  6042    6042721941
11/18/2015  11/24/2015  6056    6056681931
11/19/2015  11/25/2015  6062    6062621241
11/18/2015  11/24/2015  6064    6064847461
11/19/2015  11/25/2015  6072    6072744251
11/17/2015  11/23/2015  6090    6090839381
```

Comment: with this data what would you want your result to look like?

Comment: I just need to have the correct PO Number returned, so it shouldn't be too complex. I just couldn't figure out the date range part.

Comment: How have you handled the rest of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the search date is in G1...

If the search store is in G2...

If the data are in columns A, B, C, and D...

You can use this formula to return the **first** PO# where the search date is between the Start and End dates and where the search store matches Store #:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1,(A1:A999<=G1)*(B1:B999>=G1)*(C1:C999=G2),))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: if your data extend further down than row 999, change the 999s in the formula to a suitable row number.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I just get an #N/A value back when I enter the formula.

Comment: Did you enter it with Control-Shift-Enter?

Comment: @BobJenkins Please try again. It works. You must confirm the formula with Control-Shift-Enter instead of simply Enter.

Comment: Yes. I did just as it instructed me to do.

Comment: Does it matter what version of excel I'm using?

Comment: No. This will work in any version. Well, are you on a Mac or PC?

Comment: No. I'm using a PC. It seems as though it should work, but it isn't working.

Comment: It looks like one of my date columns wasn't formatted correctly, but after I fixed that I just get a bunch of ####s instead of the N/A.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to also change the formatting on the cell with the formula. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Yes, I was just looking and column A was text instead of dates.